# Can CiviCRM be managed as a group of companies, where there is a parent company of the group of child companies?

Tags: wordpress, profile, groups, smartgroups, settings

An example of this Group of Financial Companies, which is the Parent company, then below it, are the other daughter companies, but that each one is granted their independent clients and their personalized invoices with their logo of each one, so , that is related to the group but that they handle their data separately within the same CiviCRM structures in a single and single installation.

[image]

Comment: This might be close, but maybe not exactly: https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/install/multi-site/#install-the-first-site

Comment: Permissioned Relationships is another route but doesn't offer the customised receipts, but i don't think multi-site offers that out of the box either

Answer (score 1):

I do not think this is possible out of the box with CiviCRM, with the customized receipts and invoices being the biggest stumbling block AFAIK.

However I have built integrations with other invoicing software and you might be able to solve your issues that way, but it will require development.